# Cocos2d-x run activate() in the selected() method and disable it in ccTouchEnded?

Tags: image, subclass, cocos2d-x, selected, ccmenuitem

I'm making a subclass of CCMenuItemImage that executes it's method when the touch begins instead of when it ends. I tried running activate() in the selected() method, which works, but it is executed again as expected when the touch ends. How can I go about this? Please be specific. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
MenuItemImage->setEnable(true);//active
MenuItemImage->setEnable(false);//disactive
```